# In Webpack, how can an exports file not import everything it exports?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

I have a project that is divided into "modules".

Each module has an ***exports file*** that exports multiple files from the module.

By convention, we only require what is exposed in a module.

For example if I have the "Top Bar" and "Workspace" modules and they need to communicate, "Top Bar" exposes **Only** index.js and "Workspace" requires the desired part of the "Top Bar" from it:

TopBar/index.js:

```
export TopBarComponent from './components/TopBarComponent'

export SomethingElse from './service/SomethingElse'
```

Workspace/components/Workspace.js:

```
import {TopBarComponent} from 'TopBarComponent'
....
```

While this way the project is very modular, my problem is that when "Workspace" requires "TopBarComponent", "SomethingElse" gets imported along the way.

Any Ideas on how to prevent it with the assumption index.js of each module is an export file and only has export lines?

Comment: For webpack, just omit the `index.js` entirely. `import {TopBarComponent}` from where it is originally defined. Other, more concise bundlers (like Webpack2, Rollup perhaps?) will perform tree-shaking to get rid of unused dependencies

Comment: We avoid `import {TopBarComponent} from ../../TopBar/components/TopBarComponent` on porpoise so each module exports just the parts it wants to export and have a convention not to import from other modules directly

Comment: I'd check webpack2. thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Let me put it simple.
>
> 1. ES6 import/export should be accompanied by babel loader as it is yet not supported across browsers.
> 2. Default exports should be imported without {} and others using {}
>
> I have put a basic example in which Main.js uses TopBarComponent
>   exported values and TopBarComponent uses index.js exported values.  If you follow the basic steps there shouldn't be any problem.
>
> Eg. if you have

Please see the below code

> index.js

```
var something;
 var data = "index Data 1"
 export data
 export default "index Data 2"
```

> TopBarComponent.js

```
import defaultData , {data} from 'index'
...
..
var topbardata = "something"
export default {key : []};
export topbardata ;
```

> Main.js

```
import defaultData , {topbardata} from 'TopBarComponent'
```

> You are only exporting what you want. The rest code not included in
>   export never gets imported

Comment: The question is about "SomethingElse" being imported without ever importing it explicitly.

Comment: Alas! I am referring to the same point. Correct me if I am wrong. If you follow the approach of using the export from the same file contents as the other I haven't tried neither want to. Even if you want to export the entire file just wrap it in a function and use the export explicity using the export statement, you shall not get anything else other than what you have exported. Export/Import plays quite safe!